# How can I connect to a samba share from Windows 7 running in VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, samba

I'm sharing a couple of directories via samba from my Linux machine, and have no problem seeing them from other Windows XP boxes on the network.

Now I'm running Windows 7 as a virtual machine via VirtualBox, but I can't figure out how to connect to one of those shares.  Is it possible?  Is there a better way to get access to the file system on the host from a virtual machine?

Comment: What are the VMs network settings?

Comment: Adapter 1 is enabled, attached to "NAT".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the Windows 7 Guest additions installed?  I would just start the VM and select form the VM Menu Bar, **Devices -> Shared Folders** - you use a simple dialog allowing you to select a path on your local machine.  You can choose to make it permanent or read only.

Once you do that, you can map any of them from Windows Explorer.  Select **Tools -> Map Network Drive** and select from the **VirtualBox Shared Folders** section.

This doesn't access the samba share directly, but it works.  Not sure if you'll experience a performance problem with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

By using NAT, Virtualbox is acting as a router, and the virtual machine is therefore hidden from the world outside its router - including your network.

Try setting the network to "bridged", in this way the virtual machine uses your physical router as its router and will appear as a normal machine on your network.

Comment: I tried that, and still can't see anything.  It does see the Linksys router, but can't see any other machines on the network.  Is Win7 Home networking limited to the "homegroup" stuff, which seems to only apply to Win7 computers?